# Practical use example of Dot product and cross product?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, mathematics

Edit : Problem Solved . Thank you

I have read all Dot product and cross product related questions and answers. Thanks to explainations of some supportive community members Now  I know what dot product and cross products are and how to get them ,what their formulas are. But I still can not think of when and where both of those can be useful. 
Sorry for my Bad english and Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use the search box on the top of the page: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=dot+product and https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=cross+product

Comment: Thank you sir. I found lot of important information because of you .